# Nested Abstract class and returning abstract class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm working on creating an interface for my algorithms.

I have one base abstract class and two derived classes.
Inside the base abstract class, it has the second abstract class.
Within base derived classes, each has second derived class.

The structure would look like this:

```
class Engine {
public:
  class EngineStatus {
    // abstract class 
    ...
  };
  Engine(){};
  virtual ~Engine();
  virtual std::vector<EngineStatus*> getStatus() = 0;
private:
  std::vector<EngineStatus> m_status;
};

// Derived class
class OneEngine : public Engine {
  public OneEngineStatus : public EngineStatus {
    // Derived class
    ...
  };
  ...

  std::vector<EngineStatus*> getStatus()
  {
    return m_status;   // Compiler error...
  }
};

// Derived class
class AnotherEngine : public Engine {
  public AnotherEngineStatus : public EngineStatus {
    // Derived class
    ...
  };
  ...

  std::vector<EngineStatus*> getStatus()
  {
    return m_status;   // Compiler error...
  }
};
```

In main,

```
Engine* myEngine;
std::vector<Engine::EngineStatus*> status = myEngine->getStatus();
```

How can I accomplish this, or is there any better way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your problem, the member m_status is of type `std::vector<EngineStatus>` but your method signature returns type `std::vector<EngineStatus*>`.  So you're going to have to change m_status to be of type `std::vector<EngineStatus*>` and then have it hold onto pointers.

Comment: Are you trying to fix a compiler error?  If so, can you paste the error you're getting?.

Comment: Nevermind, I see your problem.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, but how would you put data in it?

Comment: Well without knowing what the rest of your program looks like, you could do something like this: `m_status.push_back(new EngineStatus());`  Of course, you'd have to free the allocated objects later.